# Caratheodory measure problem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $μ$ be a Caratheodory extension of an elementary measure $μ_0$ defined on a semiring $P$. Let $A$ be a measurable set with $μ(A)<∞$. Show there are sets $B,C∈σ(P)$ such that $B⊂A⊂C$ and $μ(C\setminus B)=0$.

I managed to show the existence of $C$
using the identity:

$μ(A)$=$\inf\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu(R_j):(R_j)_{j=1}^\infty\subset P, A\subset\cup_{j=1}^\infty R_j\}$

Where $μ≡μ_0$ on $P$. I used it to prove that there is a set $C∈σ(P)$ such that $A⊂C$ and $μ(A)=μ(C)$. I believe this is exactly the set $C$ I will need for the exercise. But how to find $B$? The identity I wrote is all about sets that contain $A$, but I don't know anything about the subsets of $A$ itself. I thought about using the fact that Caratheodory measure is complete and about taking the supremum of the measures of subsets of $A$ that are in $σ(P)$, but that didn't help me so far. Any ideas?

Comment: whats the definition of semiring?

Comment: A semiring $P$ on a set $X$ is subset of $2^X$ which contains the empty set, closed under finite intersections, and the difference between any two sets in $P$ can be written as a finite union of pairwise disjoint sets in $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $(R_j)$ in $P$ which satisfies the assertion on the definition of $\mu(A)$.

Given a natural $n$, there is a sequence $(R_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $S$ which satisfy $$\mu(\bigcup _j R_{j,n} - A)=\sum_j \mu(R_{j,n})-\mu(A) < \frac{1}{n}$$

So, what you say about this set: (?) $$C=\bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}R_{j,n}$$

You can prove that $C \in \sigma(P)$ and $\mu(C\setminus A)=0$.

Comment: hmm, now I've seen that this part you already did ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I did the same thing to find $C$. But the problem is that $A$ is not necessary in $\sigma(P)$. If it is then we take $A=B$ and that's it. But it may not be the case.